# Optimising Discriminator for GAN

Tags: integral, gan

For Generative Adversarial Networks, when trying to optimise for a Discriminator given a fixed Generator, we arrive at the following cost function (as in the original paper)

$V(G,D)=\int_{x}p_{data(x)}\log(D(x))+p_{g}(x)\log(1−D(x))dx$

Given that G is fixed, we can therefore maximise $V(G,D)$, however instead of taking the derivative of the above function, we instead maximise

$a\log(x)+b\log(1-x)$

and therefore end up with

$\frac{d}{dD(x)}(p_{data}(x)\log{D(x)}+p_g(x)\log{(1-D(x))} = 0$

Can anyone explain to me why we optimise the integrand instead of the integral?

Thank you!